# Dynamic SSRS LInk

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, dynamic-url

I am creating a SSRS report with dynamic URL. Content which is in bold is the system generated ticket number which I want to pull my the Fields!Change_Number.Value column.

Original URL
https://sm.com/webtier-9.50/index.do?ctx=docEngine&file=cm3r&query=number%3D%22**C945212658**%22&action=&title=Change%20**C945212658**

This is what I have tried

`="https://sm.com/webtier-9.50/index.do?ctx=docEngine&file=cm3r&query=number%3D%22Fields!Change_Number.Value%22&action=&title=Change%20"Fields!Change_Number.Value`

Error:
The ActionInfo.Action.Hyperlink expression for the text box ‘Change_Number2’ contains an error: [BC30205] End of statement expected.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to concatenate those fields: the first is within the double quote block, so it is being taken literally and adding the string 'Fields!Change_Number.Value' to the URL, not the value that you want. The second field is just bare outside the double quotes, so it doesn't know what to do with it - that is the one causing the error.

You can concatenate strings using either + or &. See: [Operators in Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/operators-in-expressions-report-builder-and-ssrs)

```
="https://sm.com/webier-9.50/index.do?ctx=docEngine&file=cm3r&query=number%3D%22" & Fields!Change_Number.Value & "%22&action=%title=Change%20" & Fields!Change_Number.Value
```

Comment: @C Black: Thank you for much for help and explanation .It's working now.

Comment: Can you do this, while showing the field, instead of the yucky hyperlink? Say the id is 12345. Can you say iff(len(field) = x, show 12345 but as a clickable hyperlink that will go to the link, show value not as a clickable link)

Comment: Nevermind. I figured it out. I needed to leave the field as the field, and the set the action to the iff statement and just format it like a hyperlink, so people will know they can click it.

Answer (score 0):

To embed a field into a dynamic URL, you don't actually embed it - you append it. Here is your URL corrected:

`="https://sm.com/webtier-9.50/index.do?ctx=docEngine&file=cm3r&query=number%3D" + Fields!Change_Number.Value + "&action=&title=Change%20" + Fields!Change_Number.Value`